# Is "export" needed when setting HISTIGNORE in bashrc files?

Tags: bash

As I understand it, `export`ing an environment variable makes it available to any processes spawned from the current one.  But the only processes that will be interested in the `HISTIGNORE` variable (and some related variables) are other instances of bash, which will read ~/.bashrc and pick up the value anyway.  So should I use:

```
export HISTIGNORE="&"
```

or just:

```
HISTIGNORE="&"
```

in my .bashrc file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For shell settings, you don't need `export`, for the reason you give. And it's better not to use it, in case some other application reacts to the same variable but doesn't interpret the value in the same way. I don't know any other application that uses `HISTIGNORE`, but the issue arises with other variables. For example, `PS1` should definitely not be exported since different shells use this variable but with different escape sequences.

Comment: Readers of this question/answer, might also find [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197333/22812) to be useful for the general case of *when to use `export`* in Bash start-up files.