# Using export in .bashrc

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I have noticed in my `.bashrc` that some lines have `export` in front of them, such as

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%b-%d  %H:%M  "
...
export MYSQL_HISTFILE="/root/.mysql_history"
```

whereas others don't, such as

```
HISTSIZE=100000
```

I am wondering if, first, this is correct, and second what the rule is for using `export` in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You only need `export` for variables that should be "seen" by other programs which you launch in the shell, while the ones that are only used inside the shell itself don't need to be `export`ed.

This is what the man page says:

> The  supplied  names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.  If the `-f` option is  given,
> the  names  refer to functions.  If no names are given, or if the `-p`
> option is supplied, a list of all names that are  exported  in  this
> shell  is  printed.   The `-n` option causes the export property to be
> removed from each name.  If a variable name is  followed  by  `=word`,
> the  value  of  the variable is set to word.  export returns an exit
> status of 0 unless an invalid option  is  encountered,  one  of  the
> names  is  not a valid shell variable name, or `-f` is supplied with a
> name that is not a function.

This can be demonstrated with the following:

```
$ MYVAR="value"
$ echo ${MYVAR}
value
$ echo 'echo ${MYVAR}' > echo.sh
$ chmod +x echo.sh
$ ./echo.sh

$ export MYVAR="value-exported"
$ ./echo.sh
value-exported
```

Explanation:

- I first set `${MYVAR}` to be a shell variable with `MYVAR="value"`. Using `echo` I can echo the value of it because echo is part of the shell.
- Then I create `echo.sh`. That's a little script that basically does the same, it just echoes `${MYVAR}`, but the difference is that it will run in a different process because it's a separate script.
- When calling `echo.sh` it outputs nothing, because the new process does not inherit `${MYVAR}`
- Then I export `${MYVAR}` into my environment with the `export` keyword
- When I now run the same `echo.sh` again, it echoes the content of `${MYVAR}` because it gets it from the environment

So to answer your question:

It depends where a variable is going to be used, whether you have to export it or not.

Answer (score 37):

Use `export` for [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Environment variables are an operating system feature. Environment variables are inherited by child processes: if you set them in a shell, they're available in all the programs started by this shell. Variables used by many applications or by specific applications other than shells are environment variables. Here are a few examples of common environment variables:

- `HOME` — indicates the user's home directory, which is where per-user configuration files are located. Used by any program that reads per-user configuration files or otherwise needs to know the location of the user's home directory.
- `PATH` — indicates where to find executable files to launch other programs. Used by every program that needs to start another program.
- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` — indicates where to find dynamic library files. Used by every dynamically linked executable.
- `EDITOR`, `VISUAL` — indicates what program to run when an editor is needed. Used by any program that needs to launch a text editor.
- `DISPLAY`, `XAUTHORITY` — indicates how to connect to the X11 server. Used by X11 clients (i.e. GUI programs).
- `LESS` — options automatically turned on when `less` is run. Used by `less`.
- `http_proxy` — indicates the web proxy to use. Used by most web browsers.

Do not use `export` for shell variables. Shell variables are a feature of the shell as a programming language. Shell variables are used only inside the shell where they are set; they have no meaning to programs launched by the shell. Shell variables are duplicated when a subshell is created, like the rest of the shell state. Here are a few examples of shell variables that have a meaning to popular shells:

- `PS1` — the prompt to display before each command.
- `IFS` — the characters that separate words in unquoted variable expansions and command substitutions.
- `HISTFILE` — a file where the shell will write the command history.

In addition to variables that are used by the shell, most shell scripts use variables for their internal purposes.

Most environment variables (e.g. `PATH`) make sense for a whole session, and should be set in `~/.profile` or a similar file. Variables that make sense only to a specific shell (e.g. `PS1`) should be set in a shell-specific file such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`. See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)

Answer (score 8):

For bash internal variables you do not need `export`. From your example
`HISTTIMEFORMAT` is used by bash itself and does not need an export 
`MYSQL_HISTFILE` is for `mysql` and that needs export otherwise `mysql` does not see it.